# Denial of service attack in Google Compute Engine running Ubuntu

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I noticed that my VM in the google cloud platform is generating DOS and wondering where that may be coming from. On further search, I noticed a file that wasn't created by me and deleted the file.

So far, I have changed the ssh port but I'm still getting *This project appears to be committing denial of service attacks*

I would like suggestions on what else I can do to prevent this in the future.

Comment: Would like to know why I was down voted

Comment: Because you don't know [ask].

Comment: The answer solved my issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm leaving here some **interesting resources** you can check to secure your Google Compute Engine instance:

- [Ubuntu SSH Guard manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/sshguard.8.html)
- [ArchLinux SSH guard guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/sshguard) (guides you through installation and setup)
- [Apache hardening guide from geekflare](https://geekflare.com/apache-web-server-hardening-security)
- [PHP security cheatsheet from OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet)
- [MySQL security guidelines](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/security-guidelines.html)

**General security advice** for Google Cloud Platform instances:

- Set [user permissions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview) at project level.
- Connect securely to your instance.
- Ensure the [project firewall](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls) is not open to everyone on the internet.
- Use a strong password and [store passwords securely](https://keepass.info/).
- [Ensure that all software is up to date](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/automatic-updates.html).
- [Monitor](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent) project usage closely via the monitoring API to identify abnormal project usage.

**To diagnose** trouble with GCE instances, [serial port output](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/get-serial-port-output) from the instance can be useful.

- You can check the serial port output by clicking on the instance name
  and then on "Serial port 1 (console)". Note that this logs are wipped
  when instances are shutdown & rebooted, and the log is not visible
  when the instance is not started.
- [Stackdriver monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/audit-logging) is also helpful to provide an audit trail to
  diagnose problems.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/security) are some hints you can check on keeping GCP projects secure.