# How i can configure Google Cloud Platform with Cloudflare-Only?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, cloudflare, ddos

I recently start using GCP but i have one thing i can't solve.

I have: 1 VM + 1 DB Instance + 1 LB. DB instance allow only conections from the VM IP. bUT THE VM IP allow traffic from all ip (if i configure the firewall to only allow CloudFlare and LB IP's the website crash and refuse conections).

Recently i was under attack, i activate the Cloudflare ddos mode, restart all and in like 6 h the attack come back with the Cloudflare activate. Wen i see mysql conections bump from 20-30 to 254 and all conections are from the IP of the VM so i think the problem are the public accesibility of the VM but i don't know how to solved it...

If i activate my firewall rules to only allow traffic from LB and Cloudflare the web refuses all conections..

Any idea what i can do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Support here, unfortunately, we do not have visibility into what is installed on your instance or what software caused the issue. 
Generally speaking you're responsible for investigating the source of the vulnerability and taking steps to mitigate it.
I'm writing here some hints that will help you:

- Make sure you keep your **firewall rules** in a **sensible manner**, *e.g. is not a good practice to have a firewall rule to allow all ingress connections on port 22 from all source IPs for obvious reasons.*
- Since you've already been rooted, **change all your passwords**: within the Cloud SQL instance, within the GCE instance, even within the GCP project.
- It's also a good idea to **check who has access to** your **service accounts**, just in case people that aren't currently working for you or your company still have access to them.
- If you're using **certificates revoke them**, **generate new ones** and **share them in a secure way** and with the **minimum required number of users**.
- Securing GCE instances is a shared responsability, in general, [**OWASP hardening guides**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Wordpress_Security_Implementation_Guideline) are really good.

---

I'm quoting some info here [from another StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48797719/my-google-compute-engine-commiting-dos-attack/48826677#48826677) that might be useful in your case:

**General security advice** for Google Cloud Platform instances:

- Set [**user permissions**](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview) at project level.
- Connect securely to your instance.
- Ensure the [**project firewall**](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls) is not open to everyone on the internet.
- Use a strong password and [**store passwords securely**](https://keepass.info/).
- [**Ensure that all software is up to date**](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/automatic-updates.html).
- [**Monitor**](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent) project usage closely via the monitoring API to identify abnormal project usage.

**To diagnose** trouble with GCE instances, [**serial port output**](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/get-serial-port-output) from the instance can be useful.

- You can check the serial port output by clicking on the instance name
  and then on "Serial port 1 (console)". Note that this logs are wipped
  when instances are shutdown & rebooted, and the log is not visible
  when the instance is not started.
- [**Stackdriver monitoring**](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/audit-logging) is also helpful to provide an audit trail to
  diagnose problems.
- You can use the Stackdriver Monitoring Console to set up [**alerting policies**](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts) matching given conditions (*under which a service is considered unhealthy*) that can be set up to trigger email/SMS notifications.
- [**This quickstart for Google Compute Engine instances**](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/quickstart-lamp) can be completed in ~10 minutes and shows the convenience of monitoring instances.

[**Here**](https://cloud.google.com/security) are some hints you can check on keeping GCP projects secure.